# firebase.getToken() not a valid token

Tags: firebase, google-api, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging, angularfire

The function that gives me the registration Token returns the following string

```
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImQyZjQ0ZGVmNmE5MDkyYzlhYmYwNzJiMzM3ZDQ3OTVkZTFmZmNjY2UifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3NlY3VyZXRva2VuLmdvb2dsZS5jb20vZGFyay1zdHJhdHVtLTE5NDAxOSIsImF1ZCI6ImRhcmstc3RyYXR1bS0xOTQwMTkiLCJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOjE1MTgxNzUzODcsInVzZXJfaWQiOiI1YTY5ZTM4NjEzZWJkYmU4MGQ0MzhiOTciLCJzdWIiOiI1YTY5ZTM4NjEzZWJkYmU4MGQ0MzhiOTciLCJpYXQiOjE1MTgxNzUzODgsImV4cCI6MTUxODE3ODk4OCwiZmlyZWJhc2UiOnsiaWRlbnRpdGllcyI6e30sInNpZ25faW5fcHJvdmlkZXIiOiJjdXN0b20ifX0.rN76re5hzXkf03MFezbE5fvqJQ0XR46HZNOm9vAlPYr5hdr5LxP7Abbu5QK733WXVtwENwcv86HH2Q_jfxMlAzKwQRlHcU9g7-2wS1Q-jPIDfmc9-DziR4IgtrmJ3wt3mKl-3yS60PJdNhXOsg0PEt70GoWwEsaIsti4MEw87c470z9M8YRtCS_Q7yeEBZCs0MOTUmvfiFLVkrboPEgOf9zv7GFfRAuF3Zt-qOx9I-4GdUksuA2_mFCXXUEZ_eHkEWEdNl_wCT1ggMy7VMlQgFmRl00FXEgGSUIBLghejGDuJFT08CVsh5oLrHp2pKNSIShRnmL9RLJgnXTEzUz39A
```

whene I use this string as a token to send message it gives me an error :

```
{
"results": [
    {
        "error": {
            "code": "messaging/invalid-registration-token",
            "message": "Invalid registration token provided. Make sure it matches the registration token the client app receives from registering with FCM."
        }
    }
],
"canonicalRegistrationTokenCount": 0,
"failureCount": 1,
"successCount": 0,
"multicastId": 5998201396286625000
}
```

I think the registration token should be in this format  :

```
cbuJIjkg9zQ:APA91bHavuWCuRuWIBrDOoHUK-RsjU1yewigurrYzHe0cP‌​iTQINykKjrLf8E0qEwJj‌​3XmJ1IoTmn0r2EoLR_mA‌​HGOjlA61CnQ8aSn2WxWK‌​KByOwbsnqoVeaeWQIeGU‌​_yh4wnZ67soLtI
```

Comment: Can you provide a code example.

Comment: this is my code to retrieve registration token  auth.$signInWithCustomToken(data.user.customToken).then(function(firebaseUser) {
            console.log("Signed in as:", firebaseUser.uid);
            console.log("Signed in as:", firebaseUser.getToken().then(function (data) {
              console.info("the token", data);
            }));
          }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log("Authentication failed:", error);
          });

Comment: and i use that token to send message : admin.messaging().sendToDevice(params.token, payload).then(function (response) {
      res.send(response)
      console.log("Successfully sent message but with error:", response.results[0].error);
    })
      .catch(function (error) {
        res.send(error)
        console.log("Error sending message:", error);
      })

Comment: It would have been much easier to read if you had updated your post with your code, including formatting. But it seems you're using the user-token and I think according to the documentation you have to get the token from the messaging object. More info here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client#access_the_registration_token

Comment: thank you i think your right , but i used the messaging object and gives me the following error :                                                                                 
       FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script. (messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration).↵    at http://localhost:3001/node_modules/firebase/firebase.js:546:225↵    at <anonymous>

Comment: and you can see that i have used localhost

Comment: I think you might have to deploy your cloud functions. According to this https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server It requires a trusted environment like an app server or other trusted environment such as Cloud Functions for Firebase.

Comment: thak you man for your help i was able to get the valid format of the token